# Adobe Flex website

Tags: flex

Is it legal to develop a money making website using Adobe Flex( Flex IDE is free for download)? Also, Is it legal to develop Flex website for customers/clients fot money?

Answer (score 2):

So long as you're not using pirated software then it's perfectly legal.